# Bitbucket runner run pipeline on self hosted

Tags: docker, bitbucket, pipeline, runner

I have a runner that run my custom pipeline, for the moment my pipeline create just a file on my container.
the pipeline have a volume mount

my linux host=/home/ubuntu/runner on my container /opt/runner

when I run not receive any error but I not find any file

Comment: When a pipeline runs, it will create a new docker container for the job. so volumes won't work.